# Php development server freezes on start

Tags: php

Hi so I'm starting to learn PHP and one of the first steps was to run the Development Server to start practicing, the line I used was:

```
php -S localhost:4000
```

But it just freezes and I get the line:

```
PHP 8.0.7 Development Server (http://localhost:4000) started
```

After waiting for a LONG amount of time I get this:

```
[Tue Jun 15 08:25:08 2021] PHP 8.0.7 Development Server (http://localhost:4000) started
[Tue Jun 15 08:50:15 2021] [::1]:62470 Accepted
[Tue Jun 15 08:50:15 2021] [::1]:62471 Accepted
[Tue Jun 15 08:50:16 2021] [::1]:62470 [404]: (null) / - No such file or directory
[Tue Jun 15 08:50:16 2021] [::1]:62470 Closing
[Tue Jun 15 08:50:18 2021] [::1]:62471 Closed without sending a request; it was probably just an unused speculative preconnection
[Tue Jun 15 08:50:18 2021] [::1]:62471 Closing
```

Could you please help me figure out what's going on?

Comment: do you have an `index.php` file in the directory where you are running the command to start the development server?

Comment: Looks like you're just reading the log file, which is being sent to standard output. If you open a browser and try to access http://localhost:4000, you should see something in the browser and also something in this log file. If you don't like standard output to the screen, redirect the output. Something like `php -S localhost:4000 >php.log`. I suspect there's nothing wrong here.

Comment: I don't have the index file, I was just following the course and it worked for them right after the install, didn't for me though

Comment: What I see going to the browser's localhost:4000 is "The requested resource / was not found on this server", is this normal behavior? I think I may be missing something here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server isn't "frozen", it's doing its job, waiting for requests and serving responses. Go to http://localhost:4000 in your web browser to request something from it.

Specifically, since you didn't specify a PHP script for it to run, it's waiting for you to request a particular file - if you have a file called "index.php", you can go to "http://localhost:4000/index.php" in your browser, if it's called "arnoldo-rocks.php", go to "http://localhost:4000/arnoldo-rocks.php", and so on.

It will carry on doing that until you kill it with Ctrl-C

If you want to run it in the background while you run other commands, and are using a Linux/Unix shell (not CMD or PowerShell), you can run it this way:

```
php -S localhost:4000 &
```

That will start it and immediately "put it into the background"; to kill it, you'll then need to run `fg` ("foreground the most recent background process"), and then type Ctrl-C

Comment: Really? I thought the expected outcome of the statement was a "Listening on http://localhost:4000" but I got those lines instead, going to the localhost I get "The requested resource / was not found on this server." so it threw me off

Comment: @ArnoldoJesusGonzalez If you get as far as an error message saying "... on this server", then _something_ is definitely listening on that port. Try going to the URL without running the command at all, and you'll see a completely different error message from your browser not being able to connect. I've updated the answer with an explanation of what you need to access.

Comment: Thanks, I'll proceed with the exercises as normal then, I thought I'd have a conflict later on because I didn't receive the "Listening" output but it's definitely doing it

Comment: @ArnoldoJesusGonzalez Maybe the output message changed slightly between PHP versions, and the example in the exercise is slightly out of date. :)